# MongoDB - How to display ObjectId and datetime as a string (using bson.json_util)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

So I am not sure how to convert an ObjectId and datetime to strings using the [bson.json_util](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html) class.

I understand you can use the `dumps` and then `loads` from pymongo cursor, but the problem is after when I loads, I still have the "_id" as an ObjectId and datetime as an datetime object.

my code:

```
all_cats = db.cats.find()
foo = dumps(all_cats)
print loads(foo)


[{
   u'c': u'this is a comment', 
   u'd': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 19, 7, 16, tzinfo=<bson.tz_util.FixedOffset object at 0x10cece7d0>), 
   u'_id': ObjectId('55329b7de73f02d1069528f5')
}]
```

So how do I convert the _id to "_id":"55329b7de73f02d1069528f5" and date to "d":"2015-04-19 07:16:00"??

Many thanks!

**EDIT**

After when all elements are converted to string i will return with Flask's jsonify - which will not complain that "_id" is an ObjectId and "d" is a datetime object

```
return jsonify(loads(foo))
```

Comment: str(all_cats[0]['_d']) will give you the _id as string 
 d contains a python date object you can format it any way you like

Comment: what happens when you do `foo[0]["_id"]`?

Comment: @nickmilon - yes thanks, i was thinking of doing that, but I don't like the fact that if i have million rows i will have to for loop through all items and cast each item from objectid to string and datetime to string

Answer (score 1):

This valuables are standar of Pymongo.

You can transform in Python using this methods:

The _ID use str(object) because is a bson.objectid.ObjectId (it is a function not a method)

The D use D.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") because is a datetime, you can change the format as you wish.

Example:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
# making a Connection with MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
#client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
# getting a Database
db = client.local
# getting a Collection
test = db['foo2']
#print test
item = test.find_one()
print 'Hello %s!' % item
#example Date
d = item['birth']
dString = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print 'D: %s' % d
print 'Type D: %s' % type(d)
print 'DString: %s' % dString
print 'Type DString: %s' % type(dString)
#example _ID
id = item['_id']
idString = str(id)
print 'ID: %s' % id
print 'Type ID: %s' % type(id)
print 'IDString: %s' % idString
print 'Type IDString: %s' % type(idString)
```